# Профилирование gprof

Tags: c++, qt, профилирование

Помогите разобраться. Куча мануалов по gprof - но они не понятные. Вот на примере

[Профилирование приложений в Qt Creator с помощью gprof](https://www.pvsm.ru/qt-2/10777)

начинаются непонятки с этого

```
   Flat profile: 
   Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds. 
   %    cumulative   self           self    total  
  time   seconds   seconds  calls  ms/call  ms/call    name   
 75.08    7.35       7.35   1500    4.90     4.90    functionB()
 24.92    9.79       2.44   1500    1.63     1.63    functionA()
```

что такое self ms/call и total ms/call? Есть [описание](https://www.opennet.ru/docs/RUS/gprof/gprof-5.html)

> self ms/call' (`собственных миллисекунд на вызов')
>
> Это поле представляет собой среднее количество миллисекунд,
> затраченных этой функцией на вызов, если эта функция профилируется.
> Иначе это поле остается пустым для этой функции.
>
> `total ms/call' (`всего миллисекунд на вызов')
>
> Это поле представляет собой среднее количество миллисекунд,
> затраченных этой функцией и ее подпрограммами на вызов, если эта
> функция профилируется. Иначе это поле остается пустым для этой
> функции.

что такое `собственных миллисекунд на вызов'? Например для functionB() - Это время затраченное на вход/выход в/из функции functionB() (т.е. на переключение контекста из main в functionB и обратно)?

Answer (score 1):

> что такое `собственных миллисекунд на вызов'? Например для functionB() - Это время затраченное на вход/выход в/из функции functionB() (т.е. на переключение контекста из main в functionB и обратно)?

Нет.
`self` и `total` — это название столбцов. т.е., соответственно, *собственное время* и *общее время*.
`ms/call` — это единицы измерения т.е. *миллисикунды/вызов*.

т.о. значение в столбце `total` — это среднее время выполнения в миллисекундах самой функции включая время выполнения всех других подпрограмм, которые она вызывает. А `self` —  *не включая* время подпрограмм. Как не сложно видеть, значение в поле `self ms/call` равно общему количеству секунд, затраченному при всех вызовах, (`self seconds`), поделённому на общее количество вызовов (`calls`) и умноженное на `1000`.

Comment: С этим всё понятно. Спасибо.